# Select em Firebird com PHP utilizando condições

Tags: php, sql, firebird

Como faço para incluir corretamente o select abaixo no código php?

Estou com dificuldades em fazer o *WHERE*.

```SQL
SELECT
    ESTOQUES.produto,
    ESTOQUES.cor,
    ESTOQUES.tamanho,
    ESTOQUES.filial,
    CODIGO_BARRAS.barra,
    ESTOQUES.saldo
FROM ESTOQUES, CODIGO_BARRAS
WHERE ESTOQUES.produto = CODIGO_BARRAS.produto
  and ESTOQUES.cor = CODIGO_BARRAS.cor
  and ESTOQUES.tamanho = CODIGO_BARRAS.tamanho  
  and ESTOQUES.filial='3' 
  and estoques.saldo>'0'
```

veja o código PHP.

```
<?php set_time_limit(10);

$servidor = '127.0.0.1:C:/xampp/meubd';

//conexão com o banco, se der erro mostrara uma mensagem.
if (!($dbh=ibase_connect($servidor, 'SYSDBA', 'masterkey')))
        die('Erro ao conectar com a base de dados: ' .  ibase_errmsg());

//Instruções SQL

$sql = 'SELECT * FROM ESTOQUES,CODIGO_BARRAS';
//Executa a instrução SQL
$query= ibase_query ($dbh, $sql);

//gera um loop com as linhas encontradas

while ($row = ibase_fetch_object ($query)) {
    //$FILIAL = $row->COD_FILIAL;
    $SALDO = $row->SALDO>'0';
    $filial = $row->FILIAL>'3';
    $teste = $saldo = $filial;

    $produto = $row->PRODUTO;
    $cor = $row->COR;
    $BARRA = $row->BARRA;

    $cBarracEstoque = $BARRA + $produto + $cor;


// RESULTADO DA CONSULTA
echo "$cBarracEstoque;$teste<br>";
}

ibase_free_result($query);//Libera a memoria usada

ibase_close($dbh);//fecha conexão com o firebird

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

encontrei a solução a solução.

```
//Instruções SQL

$sql = "SELECT * FROM ESTOQUES,CODIGO_BARRAS 
WHERE CODIGO_BARRAS.PRODUTO=ESTOQUES.PRODUTO
AND CODIGO_BARRAS.COR=ESTOQUES.COR
AND CODIGO_BARRAS.TAMANHO=ESTOQUES.TAMANHO 
AND ESTOQUES.saldo>'0' 
AND ESTOQUES.FILIAL='3'";
//Executa a instrução SQL
$query= ibase_query ($dbh, $sql);

//gera um loop com as linhas encontradas

while ($row = ibase_fetch_object ($query)) {
    //$FILIAL = $row->COD_FILIAL;
    $PRODUTO = $row->PRODUTO;
    $COR = $row->COR;
    $TAMANHO = $row->TAMANHO;
    $BARRA = $row->BARRA;
    $SALDO = $row->SALDO;

// RESULTADO DA CONSULTA
echo "$PRODUTO-$COR-$TAMANHO-$BARRA;$SALDO<br>";
}
```